# 'echo' newline suppression

Tags: bash, scripting, newline, echo

Why doesn't `$echo '-n'` write `-n` on terminal although `-n` is written within single quotes?

Comment: What language you using?

Comment: I guessed that this is a shell syntax question (ie, bash or whatever).

Comment: @tripleee - I'm not sure this question is a dup of the cited question. The question in the body seems to be different than the titular digest. Could you take a second look at it?

Comment: https://ss64.com/bash/echo.html

Comment: Isn't the duplicate for the ***opposite*** situation (unintentional vs. intentional)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Because the quotes are processed by the shell and the `echo` command receives plain `-n`. If you want to echo `-n`, you can e.g. `printf '%s\n' -n`

Comment: it's a shame `--` (end of options) isn't supported :(

Comment: Following works with bash: echo -e -n\\c

Answer (score 4):

I found that the following just works in bash:

```
echo -n PRINT_THIS
```

So, you should put -n the first place.

Comment: https://ss64.com/bash/echo.html

Answer (score 2):

You should try to use the more portable `printf` as far as possible.

Comment: Can you provide an example in your answer? (But ***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today.)

Answer (score 2):

You could try

```
echo -e '\055n'
```

Answer (score 0):

The quotes don't help because ... ugh, it's hard to explain. The shell strips the quotes off before the "echo" command itself is evaluated, so by that time they don't matter.

Try this:

```
echo - -n
```

That's not documented as working (I'm running Ubuntu Linux), but `echo` is almost certainly a built-in to whatever shell you're using, so the man page is questionable anyway. It does work for me. (I'm running `zsh` because I'm really suave and sophisticated).

**edit**: well it seems that the `bash` builtin `edit` doesn't behave that way. I don't know what to suggest; this:

```
echo '' -n
```

will give you "-n" preceded by a space, which (depending on what you're doing) might be OK.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Output `- -n`

Comment: For me that does this

> echo - -n
- -n

Comment: Hmm, well as I just noted in an edit, it probably varies from shell to shell.

Comment: Sorry I didn't get you.
Can you explain your point please?

Comment: Linux/UNIX systems support multiple command line interpreters (shells). The `echo` command is usually built in to each of those, and the exact syntax and features can vary.  You're probably using the default shell, `bash`, which doesn't work like my shell (`zsh`) does.

Comment: https://ss64.com/bash/echo.html

Answer (score 0):

Not quite there:

```
echo -e 'a-n\b\b\b '
 -n
```

Surprisingly, this works:

```
echo -e '-n\b'
-n
```

And here is a solution I can explain:

```
echo "foobar" | sed 's/.*/-n/'
-n
```

Comment: Re *"here is a solution I can explain"*: Can you reveal the explanation?

Comment: The sed command takes the "foobar" and replaces it with "-n".