# Echo newline in Bash prints literal \n

Tags: bash, echo, newline

How do I print a newline? This merely prints `\n`:

```
$ echo -e "Hello,\nWorld!"
Hello,\nWorld!
```

Comment: For those saying "it works for me", the behavior of echo varies quite a bit between versions.  Some will even print the "-e" as part of their output.  If you want predictable behavior for anything nontrivial, use printf instead (as in @sth's answer).

Comment: I could not get *any* of the suggestions in this answer working, because, as it turns out, I was attempting to use it in a function that *returns a value*, and all the echo (and printf) messages in the function were being appended to the return value *after being individually stripped of newlines*. Here is a question regarding this, with an extremely thorough answer: *https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27872069/how-to-debug-a-bash-function-that-returns-a-value-and-how-to-add-newlines-to-a/27872114* This was like a three hour mystery tour.

Comment: Also notable: in Unix & Linux Stack Exchange, the [accepted answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/219274/13260) to *How to add new lines when using echo*

Comment: echo -ne "hello\nworld"   (you needed the n flag to interpret escapes) - but as others say, different echo commands may have different results!

Comment: @Konchog `echo -n` man page entry on archlinux `       -n     do not output the trailing newline` It has nothing to do with interpreting escapes

Comment: @altu, that's correct. The purpose of the -n flag is to use \n within the formatting string. Of course you may decide to keep the trailing \n, but as you are formatting them, it's not unusual to remove them.

Comment: It works fine in Bash corresponding to [Ubuntu MATE 20.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_MATE#Releases) (Focal Fossa) - Bash version 5.0.17 (`GNU bash, version 5.0.17(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)`)

Comment: Since `echo` adds a newline by default you could always run `echo "Hello," && echo "World!"`

Comment: As search engine hits may include this one (e.g., for *"echo Bash no newline"*): See *["echo -n" prints "-n"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11193466/)* (canonical question, despite the title), *[How can I 'echo' out things without a newline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38021348/)*, and *['echo' newline suppression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2645174/)*.

Comment: Just read what POSIX says about `echo` https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/utilities/echo.html

Comment: @Konchog No, it's not. `-n` prevents `echo` from writing a trailing newline, that's it. It has nothing to do with interrupting the digraph `\n` as a literal newline character: that's what `-e` is for.

Answer (score 4144, accepted):

Use `printf` instead:

```
printf "hello\nworld\n"
```

`printf` behaves more consistently across different environments than `echo`.

Comment: or even `printf %"s\n" hello world` -- printf will reuse the format if too many arguments are given

Comment: The OP asked about echo, not printf; and @choroba's answer below, which uses the -e option, fills the bill perfectly.

Comment: @JESii: It fits if your `echo` happens to support the `-e` option.

Comment: Fair enough, @sth. Then how about the echo $'xxx' approach.

Comment: With some versions of `echo`, `-e` is just printed in the output itself so I think this answer is perfectly valid since `echo` isn't consistent here (unless we're talking about a specific version).

Comment: This is well and good if printf is available, but unlike echo sometimes printf isn't on the distro.

Comment: @bigtunacan Then you can install it or reference the other answers.  He said "You could use printf instead" and stated it's advantages.

Comment: @bigtunacan If you are using bash, which the asker specifies, then printf is a builtin command and comes with the shell (see `man bash` under "SHELL BUILTIN COMMANDS"). It's not distro-dependent in this case.

Comment: I can't seem to get `printf "#\!/bin/bash > output.sh` to work the way I would expect.

Comment: @bigtunacan Even if the OP hadn't said they're using Bash and Ubuntu, [the `printf` command has been standard for quite some time](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xcu/printf.html), and is also present as an executable, in case one's shell doesn't have it as a builtin. [`printf` is regarded as the portable, reliable choice.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803) You said "unlike echo sometimes printf isn't on the distro"--are there real examples of Unix-like (even if not generally POSIX-conforming) operating systems, that people actually use, that don't have a `printf` command?

Comment: I'm on WSL (Ubuntu 18.04) and I get this error: bash: printf: - : invalid option
printf: usage: printf [-v var] format [arguments]

Comment: Oh, for anyone else having the same issue with printf as mine try: `printf "%b" "hello\nworld\n"` Also to read more: https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/printf

Comment: @rustyx, that's true in C, not in bash. (Fixed format strings are good practice even in bash, yes; exploitable in the conventional way -- which is to say, on account of code making assumptions about location of variables on the stack and thus performing invalid reads -- not at all; the only issues that happen in bash are wrt. data that should be literal being instead treated as directives).

Comment: @bigtunacan, `printf` **is POSIX-specified** in far more detail than `echo` is. That is to say, many different `echo` behaviors can call themselves POSIX-compliant, but **every** POSIX-compliant UNIX will have a `printf` command that behaves exactly the same way included (for all the standard-defined operators).

Comment: I tried `printf`, but I end up with a trailing seemingly selected '%' sign. `printf "abc"` => ouputs `abc%` (running zsh on Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster))
Thus falling back to the `echo -e` option

Comment: @Wasabi Do you maybe miss a trailing `\n` and the `%` is your shell prompt?

Comment: @sth That indeed fixes the problem, but why then does the behavior change (no trailing %) when using bash or sh ? I am missing some piece information on zsh behavior ?

Comment: @Wasabi: The `%` is not printed by `printf`, it's printed by zsh as part of its command prompt. Bash uses `$` or something more complicated instead, that's why it looks different with bash. `printf` prints the same thing both times, and following that the shell prints it's command prompt. This command prompt looks different in zsh than in bash/sh.

Comment: @sth In this case, it's `zsh` printing a `%` to indicate that there was no trailing newline in the output, before unconditionally putting the prompt on the next line. (`bash`, by contrast, would simply print the prompt on the same line as the last of the output.) `zsh`'s behavior is controlled by the `PROMPT_SP` and `PROMPT_EOL_MARK` options.

Answer (score 2326):

Make sure you are in Bash.

```
$ echo $0
bash
```

All these four ways work for me:

```
echo -e "Hello\nworld"
echo -e 'Hello\nworld'
echo Hello$'\n'world
echo Hello ; echo world
```

Comment: -e flag did it for me, which "enables interpretation of backslash escapes"

Comment: I think ```-e``` param doesn't exist on all *nix OS

Comment: @kenorb: It exists in bash. It is a builtin.

Comment: Why does the third one work? Without the $ it returns "Hello n world"

Comment: One more way: `echo -e hello\\nworld`

Comment: As mentioned by various other -e does NOT work for all distributions and versions.  In some cases it is ignored and in others it will actually be printed out.  I don't believe this fixed it for the OP so should not be accepted answer

Comment: @csga5000: the third option should work regardless of the version. Moreover, this isn't the accepted answer.

Comment: @choroba Good point, the third option is a good solution.  And I know it's not, I just was just countering the comment saying it should be accepted answer (which had 43 upvotes)

Comment: just type 'man echo' in the terminal and then it is clear that for enabling interpretation of backslash sequences we need to add '-e'; the documentation also provides all the common backslash sequences that can be interpreted.

Comment: @Sheetalgupta: But `help echo` (in bash) shows a different page that describes the bash builtin.

Comment: **man bash** and **help echo** show the same information for me ,rather **man bash** more detailed official documentation

Comment: man bash and help echo show the same information, but `man echo` doesn't.

Comment: "Are you sure you're in bash?" It's the `echo -e` flag that makes this work as expected.

Comment: @Christian: In other shells, the builtin `echo` doesn't have to support the `-e` flag. That's why I asked.

Comment: @kenorb: except when 'echo' is not a builtin, but '/bin/echo'

Comment: At this point may I ask what the difference between `echo -e` and `printf`? Are there any performance penalties for using `printf`? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @ozanmuyes: `echo -e` might not be supported in other shells. `echo` doesn't understand the `%` placeholders that `printf` uses.

Comment: @xamid Just know that the `&` makes a process go in background,  so I would  try  `echo Hello && echo world`   (the difference here is **&&** instead of **&**)

Comment: You are right, `&&` is what I meant (`&` prints some undesired extra message about completion of the task). Plus `echo Hello && echo world` even works on Windows (where `A && B` means to execute `B` only when `A` executed successfully).

Comment: yea; another thing is `;` if you simply don't care about the exit code(if the prev.commands was run s.fully or failed) it's shorter too, so yea, and have a nice day!

Answer (score 752):

```
echo $'hello\nworld'
```

prints

```
hello
world
```

`$''` strings use [ANSI C Quoting](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/ANSI_002dC-Quoting.html):

> Character sequences of the form `$’string’` are treated as a special kind of single quotes. The sequence expands to string, with backslash-escaped characters in string replaced as specified by the ANSI C standard.

Comment: @EvgeniSergeev Not sure what you mean, but it didn't work for me either first. And that's because I was using double quotes and turns out this works only with single quotes! Tried in Terminal on Mac.

Comment: Problems with variables in the string not being expanded.

Comment: You can still concatenate double-quote strings. `
foo="bar"; echo $''$foo'efoot'`

Comment: It woks on `GNU bash, version 4.4.23(1)-release (x86_64-pc-msys) W10 ` like a charm.

Comment: This also works for `read -p prompt`: `read -p $'Quick!\n' -t 1`

Comment: PSA, not `sh` compatible

Answer (score 207):

You could always do `echo ""`.

For example,

```
echo "Hello,"
echo ""
echo "World!"
```

Comment: `echo ""` works for me and I think it's the simplest form to print a new line, even if this doesn't directly answer the question. Cheers.

Comment: I think it's less obvious (and thus potentially more confusing) than `echo -en "\n"`.

Comment: `echo` is enough to obtain an empty line

Comment: The `\n` did not work when you are using the `read`. But your method worked for adding a line.

Comment: i had trouble getting the other answers to work on Mac. i ended up going with this incredibly obvious solution. :)

Comment: Doesn't this put 2 newlines between Hello and World ? Upvoted anyway because I value simplicity and clarity.

Answer (score 73):

On the off chance that someone finds themselves beating their head against the wall trying to figure out why a coworker's script won't print newlines, look out for this:

```
#!/bin/bash
function GET_RECORDS()
{
   echo -e "starting\n the process";
}

echo $(GET_RECORDS);
```

As in the above, the actual running of the method may itself be wrapped in an echo which supersedes any echos that may be in the method itself.  Obviously, I watered this down for brevity. It was not so easy to spot!

You can then inform your comrades that a better way to execute functions would be like so:

```
#!/bin/bash
function GET_RECORDS()
{
   echo -e "starting\n the process";
}

GET_RECORDS;
```

Comment: Be sure you wrap the variable with quotes before echoing it out of the method.

Answer (score 42):

Simply type

```
echo
```

to get a new line

Comment: Vastly underrated answer, can't believe this question has amassed 20+ answers since 2011 and that not one of them contains this simple solution.

Comment: @Ahi Tuna: Please use your console keyboard shortcuts instead :)

Comment: @RSun and how would I do that on a Debian terminal window on a Chromebook?

Comment: @AhiTuna  printf "\033c"

Comment: On the screen-clearing, Ctrl+L will also clear the screen on the majority of terminals.

Comment: @AhiTuna to clear screen, just type `clear` command

Answer (score 37):

For only the question asked (not special characters etc) changing only double quotes to single quotes.

```
echo -e 'Hello,\nWorld!'
```

Results in:

```
Hello,
World!
```

Comment: Tested with double quotes in `RHEL 9.7` and works fine.

Answer (score 33):

**POSIX 7 on echo**

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html

`-e` is not defined and backslashes are implementation defined:

> If the first operand is -n, or if any of the operands contain a <backslash> character, the results are implementation-defined.

unless you have an optional XSI extension.

So I recommend that you should use [`printf`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/printf.html) instead, which is well specified:

> format operand shall be used as the format string described in XBD File Format Notation [...]

the [File Format Notation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap05.html#tag_05):

> \n <newline> Move the printing position to the start of the next line.

Also keep in mind that Ubuntu 15.10 and most distros implement `echo` both as:

- a Bash built-in: `help echo`
- a standalone executable: `which echo`

which can lead to some confusion.

Answer (score 22):

```
str='hello\nworld'
$ echo | sed "i$str"
hello
world
```

Comment: This is actually a great answer since it works for string concatenations. Great!

Comment: Why bother to invoke a second program? It's not that we are trying to write a real time application in bash ;) but its not necessary.

Answer (score 16):

You can also do:

```
echo "hello
world"
```

This works both inside a script and from the command line.

On the command line, press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to do the line break inside the string.

This works for me on my macOS and my [Ubuntu 18.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_18.04_LTS_.28Bionic_Beaver.29) (Bionic Beaver) system.

Answer (score 12):

There is a *new* [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) added in Bash 4.4 that interprets escape sequences:

> **`${parameter@operator} - E operator`**
>
> The expansion is a string that is the value of parameter with
> backslash escape sequences expanded as with the `$'…'` quoting
> mechanism.

```
$ foo='hello\nworld'
$ echo "${foo@E}"
hello
world
```

Comment: worked like a charm for printing a message that was a variable inside a function, from outside the function.

Answer (score 11):

I just use echo without any arguments:

```
echo "Hello"
echo
echo "World"
```

Comment: This is wrong as `Hello` is followed by two line breaks and not only one.

Answer (score 10):

To print a new line with echo, use:

```
echo
```

or

```
echo -e '\n'
```

Answer (score 6):

My script:

```
echo "WARNINGS: $warningsFound WARNINGS FOUND:\n$warningStrings
```

Output:

```
WARNING : 2 WARNINGS FOUND:\nWarning, found the following local orphaned signature file:
```

On my Bash script I was getting mad as you until I've just tried:

```
echo "WARNING : $warningsFound WARNINGS FOUND:
$warningStrings"
```

Just hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> where you want to insert that jump. The output now is:

```
WARNING : 2 WARNINGS FOUND:
Warning, found the following local orphaned signature file:
```

Comment: Just a note, you will probably want to use ${ } around your variable names as not doing so can lead to really weird behavior when  a shell finds a variable called $warningsFound and prints that and not the two separate outputs.

Comment: @dragon788 maybe I'm missing something, but the variable IS actually called $warningsFound ?

Comment: I missed a word on that. If you had a variable called $warnings, in some cases without using ${warningsFound}, you could potentially end up with the contents of $warnings + "Found" instead of the variable you intended.

Answer (score 6):

This could better be done as

```
x="\n"
echo -ne $x
```

-e option will interpret backslahes for the escape sequence
-n option will remove the trailing newline in the output

PS: the command echo has an effect of always including a trailing newline in the output so -n is required to turn that thing off (and make it less confusing)

Comment: echo -ne "hello\nworld"  for the exact answer of the question :)

Answer (score 6):

If you're writing scripts and will be echoing newlines as part of other messages several times, a nice cross-platform solution is to put a literal newline in a variable like so:

```
newline='
'

echo "first line${newline}second line"
echo "Error: example error message n${newline}${usage}" >&2 #requires usage to be defined
```

Answer (score 5):

If the previous answers don't work, and there is a need to get a return value from their function:

```
function foo()
{
    local v="Dimi";
    local s="";
    .....
    s+="Some message here $v $1\n"
    .....
    echo $s
}

r=$(foo "my message");
echo -e $r;
```

Only this trick worked on a Linux system I was working on with this Bash version:

```
GNU bash, version 2.2.25(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)
```

Answer (score 4):

In a `.command` file in MacOS, the following works;

- `echo $'\nAll \nis \ndone!'`
- `echo -e $"\nAll \nis \ndone!"`
- `echo $'\n'`

[macos](/questions/tagged/macos) [.command](/questions/tagged/.command) [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) [echo](/questions/tagged/echo) [newline](/questions/tagged/newline)

Answer (score 3):

You could also use echo with braces,

```
$ (echo hello; echo world)
hello
world
```

Comment: syntax error near unexpected token `(' when called in .sh file

Comment: try `echo hello; echo world`

Comment: Or "echo hello && echo world" or just:"
echo hello
echo world

Comment: An explanation would be in order.

Answer (score 2):

This got me there....

```
outstuff=RESOURCE_GROUP=[$RESOURCE_GROUP]\\nAKS_CLUSTER_NAME=[$AKS_CLUSTER_NAME]\\nREGION_NAME=[$REGION_NAME]\\nVERSION=[$VERSION]\\nSUBNET-ID=[$SUBNET_ID]
printf $outstuff
```

Yields:

```
RESOURCE_GROUP=[akswork-rg]
AKS_CLUSTER_NAME=[aksworkshop-804]
REGION_NAME=[eastus]
VERSION=[1.16.7]
SUBNET-ID=[/subscriptions/{subidhere}/resourceGroups/makeakswork-rg/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/aks-vnet/subnets/aks-subnet]
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order. E.g, what is the gist/idea? Please respond by [editing your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61732665/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Comment: This is a good use when you can't add quotes!

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you can pass multiple strings separated by a space and it will be interpreted as `\n`.

For example when using a shell script for multi-line notifcations:

```
#!/bin/bash
notify-send 'notification success' 'another line' 'time now '`date +"%s"`
```

Comment: This is incorrect. It is never interpreted as `\n`. It is interpreted as a separate argument to the program, and the program itself may display that argument on a new line, but that doesn't mean that it was converted to `\n` at any point and is entirely dependent on the program.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to add that when you try to echo lines after running a process in the background, like `some_script &`, you lost the implicit `\r` (carriage return) in a new line so the output of:

```
some_script &
echo "firsf"
echo "second"
```

could be something like:

```
fist
    second
```

There is a line break, but not a "carriage return", to fix this, we could add `\r`:

```
echo -e 'fist\r'
echo -e 'second\r'
```

Answer (score -1):

You can just use PHP_EOL

```
echo "Hello" . PHP_EOL . "World";
```

result in console :

```
Hello
World
```

Answer (score -5):

Additional solution:

In cases, you have to echo a multiline of the long contents (such as code/ configurations)

For example:

- A Bash script to generate codes/ configurations

`echo -e`,
`printf` might have some limitation

You can use some special char as a placeholder as a line break (such as `~`) and replace it after the file was created using `tr`:

```
echo ${content} | tr '~' '\n' > $targetFile
```

It needs to invoke another program (`tr`) which should be fine, IMO.

Comment: This is a poor solution. There is absolutely no need to invoke `tr` in this case. Furthermore, what if the text includes a `~` already?

Answer (score -5):

With [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.6):

```
$ jq -nr '"Hello,\nWorld"'
Hello,
World
```