# Calling an executable program using awk

Tags: shell, awk

I have a program in C that I want to call by using awk in shell scripting. How can I do something like this?

Comment: A compiled c program is just a program... Just run it like you would any command line operation...

Comment: You can call `system()` with awk to execute commands. Perhaps you could explain your needs further since there is a better method of going about this >90% of the time.

Comment: this is usually the wrong approach. If you post a small awk script and explain when you want to call your C program we can tell either how to do that or what a better approach would be.

Answer (score 70):

From the AWK man page:

```
system(cmd)
              executes cmd and returns its exit status
```

The GNU AWK [manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html) also has [a section](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#I_002fO-Functions) that, in part, describes the `system` function and provides an example:

```
system("date | mail -s 'awk run done' root")
```

Comment: thank  you for your help! i have a shell command in busybox: logread -f| awk { if..... } and inside the awk i want to call my program in c when an if statement is true with arguments. can you give me a hint?

Comment: try `logread -f | awk '{ if(condition01){system("yourCprogram arguments")} }'`

Comment: @user2030431 You would be nice to readers if you would update your question with these/more details. And yes, I know its a bit late for that :)

Answer (score 41):

A much more robust way would be to use the `getline()` function of GNU `awk` to use a variable from a pipe. In form `cmd | getline` result, `cmd` is run, then its output is piped to `getline`. It returns `1` if got output, `0` if EOF, `-1` on failure.

First construct the command to run in a variable in the `BEGIN` clause if the command is *not* dependant on the contents of the file, e.g. a simple `date` or an `ls`.

A simple example of the above would be

```
awk 'BEGIN {
    cmd = "ls -lrth"
    while ( ( cmd | getline result ) > 0 ) {
        print result
    }
    close(cmd);
}'
```

When the command to run is part of the columnar content of a file, you generate the `cmd` string in the main `{..}` as below. E.g. consider a file whose `$2` contains the name of the file and you want it to be replaced with the `md5sum` hash content of the file. You can do

```
awk '{ cmd = "md5sum "$2
       while ( ( cmd | getline md5result ) > 0 ) { 
           $2 = md5result
       }
       close(cmd);
 }1'
```

Another frequent usage involving external commands in `awk` is during `date` processing when your `awk` does not support time functions out of the box with `mktime()`, `strftime()` functions.

Consider a case when you have Unix EPOCH timestamp stored in a column and you want to convert that to a human readable date format. Assuming GNU `date` is available

```
awk '{ cmd = "date -d @" $1 " +\"%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S\"" 
       while ( ( cmd | getline fmtDate) > 0 ) { 
           $1 = fmtDate
       }
       close(cmd);
}1'
```

for an input string as

```
1572608319 foo bar zoo
```

the above command produces an output as

```
01-11-2019 07:38:39 foo bar zoo
```

The command can be tailored to modify the `date` fields on any of the columns in a given line. Note that `-d` is a GNU specific extension, the *BSD variants support `-f` ( though not exactly similar to `-d`).

More information about `getline` can be referred to from this [AllAboutGetline](http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline) article at [awk.freeshell.org](http://awk.freeshell.org/) page.

Comment: This works great! What's the reason for using a while loop for the command instead of doing `cmd | getline fmtDate`?

Comment: @MatthiasBraun: In case of a multi-line output, the loop runs, till every last line is read. The `if` is for just a one time invocation

Answer (score 37):

There are several ways.

1. awk has a `system()` function that will run a shell command:

   `system("cmd")`
2. You can print to a pipe:

   `print "blah" | "cmd"`
3. You can have awk construct commands, and pipe all the output to the shell:

   `awk 'some script' | sh`

Answer (score 7):

Something as simple as this will work

```
awk 'BEGIN{system("echo hello")}'
```

and

`awk 'BEGIN { system("date"); close("date")}'`

Answer (score 5):

I use the power of awk to delete some of my stopped docker containers. Observe carefully how i construct the `cmd` string first before passing it to `system`.

`docker ps -a | awk '$3 ~ "/bin/clish" { cmd="docker rm "$1;system(cmd)}'`

Here, I use the 3rd column having the pattern "/bin/clish" and then I extract the container ID in the first column to construct my `cmd` string and passed that to `system`.

Answer (score 4):

It really depends :) One of the handy linux core utils (`info coreutils`) is `xargs`. If you are using `awk` you probably have a more involved  use-case in mind - your question is not very detailled.

```
printf "1 2\n3 4" | awk '{ print $2 }' | xargs touch
```

Will execute `touch 2 4`. Here `touch` could be replaced by your program. More info at `info xargs` and `man xargs` (really, *read these*).
I believe you would like to replace `touch` with your program.

**Breakdown** of beforementioned script:

```
printf "1 2\n3 4"
# Output:
1 2
3 4

# The pipe (|) makes the output of the left command the input of
# the right command (simplified)
printf "1 2\n3 4" | awk '{ print $2 }'
# Output (of the awk command):
2
4

# xargs will execute a command with arguments. The arguments
# are made up taking the input to xargs (in this case the output
# of the awk command, which is "2 4".
printf "1 2\n3 4" | awk '{ print $2 }' | xargs touch
# No output, but executes: `touch 2 4` which will create (or update
# timestamp if the files already exist) files with the name "2" and "4"
```

**Update** In the original answer, I used `echo` instead of `printf`. However, `printf` is the better and more portable alternative as was pointed out by a comment (where great links with discussions can be found).

Comment: @MountainX In which way does it work (incorrectly)? Which Operating System and Shell do you use?

Comment: In Arch Linux and bash, here are my results: [user@comp1 ~]$ echo "1 2\n3 4" | awk '{ print $2 }' | xargs touch
[user@comp1 ~]$ ls -la
-rw-rw---- 1 user user       0 Mar  7 13:34  2n3

Comment: problem may be the one discussed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8467424/echo-newline-in-bash-prints-literal-n. The following works for me: printf "1 2\n3 4" | awk '{ print $2 }' | xargs touch

Comment: Good picks and thanks for the feedback. Will update the example.

Answer (score 3):

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {
    command = "ls -lh"

    command |getline
}
```

Runs "ls -lh" in an awk script

Answer (score 1):

You can call easily with parameters via the system argument.
For example, to kill jobs corresponding to a certain string (we can otherly of course) :

```
 ps aux | grep my_searched_string | awk '{system("kill " $2)}'
```

Answer (score 1):

One more example just for fun, the problem with system("date") is that it adds linefeed on return.

```
/usr/bin/awk -v compareme="${checkvalue}" -v day="$(date)" -F"fieldseparator =" '{if ($2 == compareme){ print day " this OK" } else {print day " but this NOK" }}' inputfileORpiped
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to have this done via below method

```
cat ../logs/em2.log.1 |grep -i 192.168.21.15 |awk '{system(`date`); print $1}'
```

awk has a function called system it enables you to execute any linux bash command within the output of awk.