# How to translate a column value in the file using awk with tr command in unix

Tags: awk

### Details:

Input file : file.txt

```
P123456789,COLUMN2
P123456790,COLUMN2
P123456791,COLUMN2
```

Expected output:

```
Z678999999,COLUMN2
Z678999995,COLUMN2
Z678999996,COLUMN2
```

If i try using a variable it is giving proper result.

```
(i.e) /tmp>echo "P123456789"|tr "0-9" "5-9"|tr "A-Z" "X-Z"
Z678999999
```

But if i do with awk command it is not giving result instead giving error:

```
/tmp>$ awk 'BEGIN { FS=OFS="," } { $1=echo $1|tr "0-9" "5-9"|tr "A-Z" "X-Z";$2="COLUMN2"); print }' /tmp/file.txt >/tmp/file.txt.tmp
awk: BEGIN { FS=OFS="," } { $1=echo $1|tr "0-9" "5-9"|tr "A-Z" "X-Z";$2="COLUMN2"); print }
awk:                                   ^ syntax error
awk: BEGIN { FS=OFS="," } { $1=echo $1|tr "0-9" "5-9"|tr "A-Z" "X-Z";$2="COLUMN2"); print }
awk:                                                  ^ syntax error
awk: BEGIN { FS=OFS="," } { $1=echo $1|tr "0-9" "5-9"|tr "A-Z" "X-Z";$2="COLUMN2"); print }
awk:                                                                             ^ syntax error
```

Can anyone help please?

Comment: awk is not shell, just like C is not shell. You can no more call a shell command from an awk program than you could call it from a C program.

Comment: Check this link:  [calling-an-executable-program-using-awk](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14634349/calling-an-executable-program-using-awk).  You could also look up `getline` answers( see Kent's answer ), or learn enough awk to manipulate the data within awk entirely.

Answer (score 2):

just do what you wanted, without changing your logic:

awk line:

```
awk -F, -v OFS="," '{ "echo \""$1"\"|tr \"0-9\" \"5-9\"|tr \"A-Z\" \"X-Z\"" |getline $1}7'
```

with your data:

```
kent$  echo "P123456789,COLUMN2
P123456790,COLUMN2
P123456791,COLUMN2"|awk -F, -v OFS="," '{ "echo \""$1"\"|tr \"0-9\" \"5-9\"|tr \"A-Z\" \"X-Z\"" |getline $1}7'                                                              
Z678999999,COLUMN2
Z678999995,COLUMN2
Z678999996,COLUMN2
```

Comment: It is still giving error :            /tmp>$ cat  aml_test.txt|awk -F, -v OFS="," '{ "echo \""$1"\"|tr \"0-9\" \"5-9\"|tr \"A-Z\" \"X-Z\"" |getline $1}7'
sh: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
P123456789,COLUMN2
P123456790,COLUMN2
P123456791,COLUMN2

Comment: try the same command in my answer, see if it worked. don't know how your data look like. @Murali

Comment: +1, but what's the mysterious `7` at the end? Just a non-zero integer to create an always-true pattern that results in printing the current line? Did you mean to use `1`?

Comment: @mklement0 yes. but pressing 7 is easier for me than 1

Comment: Kent, can you please help ? While i ran your command with the same as u given above i am getting error

Comment: /tmp>$ echo "P123456789,COLUMN2 > P123456790,COLUMN2 > P123456791,COLUMN2"|awk -F, -v OFS="," '{ "echo \""$1"\"|tr \"0-9\" \"5-9\"|tr \"A-Z\" \"X-Z\"" |getline $1}7' sh: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"' sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat tst.awk
function tr(old,new,str,        oldA,newA,strA,i,j) {
    split(old,oldA,"")
    split(new,newA,"")
    split(str,strA,"")
    str = ""
    for (i=1;i in strA;i++) {
        for (j=1;(j in oldA) && !sub(oldA[j],newA[j],strA[i]);j++)
            ;
        str = str strA[i]
    }
    return str
}

BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }
{ print tr("P012345678","Z567899999",$1), $2 }

$ awk -f tst.awk file
Z678999999,COLUMN2
Z678999995,COLUMN2
Z678999996,COLUMN2
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, AWK does not have a built in translation function. You could write one like [Ed Morton](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21767181/751863) has done, but I would reach for (and highly recommend) a more powerful tool. Perl, for example, can process fields using the autosplit (`-a`) command switch:

> -a   turns on autosplit mode when used with a -n or -p.  An implicit split command to the @F array is done as the first thing inside the
>   implicit while loop produced by the -n or -p.

You can type `perldoc perlrun` for more details.

Here's my solution:

```
perl -F, -lane '$F[0] =~ tr/0-9/5-9/; $F[0] =~ tr/A-Z/X-Z/; print join (",", @F)' file.txt
```

Results:

```
Z678999999,COLUMN2
Z678999995,COLUMN2
Z678999996,COLUMN2
```

Comment: Thanks Steve!!! Wonderful. I came to see that awk is running as C program so it would not allow to use unix commands, so i tried by system command for the translation part it worked for me. But i believe my way of approach would take processing time rather i will go by your approach

Comment: Even the below approach we can follow but depends on the processing speed we should choose the approach. >/tmp>$ awk 'BEGIN { FS=OFS="," } { $1=system("echo "$1"|tr '0-9' '5-9'|tr 'A-Z' 'X-Z'");$2="COLUMN2"} ' /tmp/file.txt >Result:=========== Z678999999 Z678999995 Z678999996

Comment: @Murali: `system()` returns the command's _exit code_, not its stdout output; see @Kent's answer for capturing shell command output in a variable with `getline`.

Comment: @Murali: If you have the time, I'd be interested in seeing the benchmark of the three answers. My bet is that the Perl is the slowest, but the difference may only be negligible.