# How to get the commit id of all git repository heads inside a project?

Tags: git, shell, command, repo

Let's say the directory name ABC is my project which is not a git repository.
Inside that dir ABC i have many directories which are git repository respectively.
And i want every git repository's commit id of their heads with a single command (repo or git command) or script.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Bash,

```
find ABC -name .git | awk '{
    cmd = "GIT_DIR="$NF" git rev-parse HEAD"
    while ( ( cmd | getline result ) > 0 ) {
        print $NF, result
    }
    close(cmd)
}'
```

The script iterates all `.git` under `ABC`, assuming that they are all git repositories, runs `git rev-parse HEAD` in each to get the head commit, and prints the repository folders and the SHA1 values.

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55278818/6330106

Comment: What if some dir are nested and repository respectively? Actually some sub dir inside ABC are nested dir and are repository too.