# Use a system call in an awk script

Tags: bash, awk

I'm trying to run an awk script which calls a bash command and uses the output to filter sonme results.

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {

        cmd = system("ls -la")                                                                                                                    
        cmd | $1 \~ /\[aA\]\[dD\]{2}\[rR\]{eE}\[sS\]{2}/ {print $0}                                                                                        
                                                                                                                                                  
        # Also tried
        $1 \~ /\[aA\]\[dD\]{2}\[rR\]{eE}\[sS\]{2}/ {print $0} cmd
    
        close(cmd)

}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calling an executable program using awk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14634349/calling-an-executable-program-using-awk)

Comment: From the awk man page: _system(cmd) : executes cmd and **returns its exit status**_!! This is certainly not what you want here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't call `system()` for that. Change this:

```
cmd = system("ls -la")                                                                                                                    
cmd | $1 \~ /\[aA\]\[dD\]{2}\[rR\]{eE}\[sS\]{2}/ {print $0}
close(cmd)
```

to this:

```
cmd = "ls -la"
while ( (cmd | getline) > 0 ) {
    if ( $1 ~ /[aA][dD]{2}[rR]{eE}[sS]{2}/ ) {print $0}
}
close(cmd)
```

Also, see

- http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline for how/when to use `getline`,
- https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs for why not to parse the output of `ls`, and
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/563456/133219 for why not to use a shebang to call awk.

By the way, to do a case-insensitive comparison consider simply:

```
tolower($1) ~ /address/
```

instead of putting the upper and lower case of each letter inside a bracket expression `[dD]` (and it's clearer/simpler without using RE intervals `dd` vs `d{2}`).

Comment: @suzkirch no, nothing.