# Using jq to parse keys present in two lists (even though it might not exist in one of those)

Tags: json, bash, jq

*(It was hard to come up with a title that summarizes the issue, so feel free to improve it).*

I have a JSON file with the following content:

```
{
    "Items": [
        {
            "ID": {
                "S": "ID_Complete"
            }, 
            "oldProperties": {
                "L": [
                    {
                        "S": "[property_A : value_A_old]"
                    }, 
                    {
                        "S": "[property_B : value_B_old]"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "newProperties": {
                "L": [
                    {
                        "S": "[property_A : value_A_new]"
                    }, 
                    {
                        "S": "[property_B : value_B_new]"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }, 
        {
            "ID": {
                "S": "ID_Incomplete"
            }, 
            "oldProperties": {
                "L": [
                    {
                        "S": "[property_B : value_B_old]"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "newProperties": {
                "L": [
                    {
                        "S": "[property_A : value_A_new]"
                    }, 
                    {
                        "S": "[property_B : value_B_new]"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I would like to manipulate the data using `jq` in such a way that for each item in `Items[]` that has a ***new*** value for *property_A* (under ***newProperties*** list) generate an output with the corresponding *id*, *old* and *new* (see desired output below) fields regardless of the value that property has in the ***oldProperties*** list. Moreover, if *property_A* does not exist in the ***oldProperties***, I still need the *old* field to be populated with a `null` (or any fixed string for what it's worth).

Desired output:

```
{
  "id": "id_Complete",
  "old": "[property_A : value_A_old]",
  "new": "[property_A : value_A_new]"
}
{
  "id": "ID_Incomplete",
  "old": null,
  "new": "[property_A : value_A_new]"
}
```

**Note:** Even though *property_A* doesn't exist in the ***oldProperties*** list, other properties may (and will) exist.

The problem I am facing is that I am not able to get an output when the desired property does not exist in the ***oldProperties*** list. My current `jq` command looks like this:

```
jq -r '.Items[] | 
    { id:.ID.S, 
      old:.oldProperties.L[].S | select(. | contains("property_A")),
      new:.newProperties.L[].S | select(. | contains("property_A")) }'
```

Which renders only the *ID_Complete* case, while I need the other as well.

Is there any way to achieve this using this tool?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This filter produces the desired output.

```
def parse: capture("(?<key>\\w+)\\s*:\\s*(?<value>\\w+)") ;
def print: "[\(.key) : \(.value)]";
def norm:   [.[][][] | parse | select(.key=="property_A") | print][0];

  .Items
| map({id:.ID.S, old:.oldProperties|norm, new:.newProperties|norm})[]
```

Sample Run (assumes filter in `filter.jq` and data in `data.json`)

```
$ jq -M -f filter.jq data.json
{
  "id": "ID_Complete",
  "old": "[property_A : value_A_old]",
  "new": "[property_A : value_A_new]"
}
{
  "id": "ID_Incomplete",
  "old": null,
  "new": "[property_A : value_A_new]"
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##xZJBS8MwFMfv/RSPnFpdg@fMKZu7DDwIO6ahlO0J1TaJaeoYa7@69TUVZV5kJwkkL8nv/395j7y8DSe28Vg3TEiK1kyc2JYJivIHU9sKPbJ@xky1f3LGovMlNiPzGPiRlHa6OOZLEPBeVC3my5wEioS/kdU3svpCFLlrPFzmToK/3CdE9SN1VtZG7y4t7B9erfpu2OMz2MI1KGBXWN86jFl8f/uKx7ssO1wnWdZciXGiw2AwHbME5lHQulJ7AUxmMSdRQnkoCmSi2MRo42oBAJJLNQ7oppS0NljhzgfpYsF@KiL/bvJW8kbNowiAhy8UdVAXNj6Ve8E3a76dATVL8LMWd2PCGVCdgp81MFz0iVRkBxBFw/BhrC@NboY01W1VpaW2raeNKw6paT1tPgE)

Comment: Awesome response, thanks. Both this and the other work. Before accepting one however, I will be trying them out within the system that is already in place and see which of both can be better adapted to it (since the question presented a working and trimmed down example of a small portion of the data).

Answer (score 2):

Your list of properties appear to be values of some object. You could map them out into an object to then diff the objects, then report on the results.

You could do something like this:

```
def make_object_from_properties:
      [.L[].S | capture("\\[(?<key>\\w+) : (?<value>\\w+)\\]")]
    | from_entries
    ;
def diff_objects($old; $new):
      def _prop($key): select(has($key))[$key];
      ([($old | keys[]), ($new | keys[])] | unique) as $keys
    | [   $keys[] as $k
        | ({ value: $old | _prop($k) } // { none: true }) as $o
        | ({ value: $new | _prop($k) } // { none: true }) as $n
        | (if   $o.none                 then "add"
          elif  $n.none                 then "remove"
          elif  $o.value != $n.value    then "change"
                                        else "same"
          end) as $s
        | { key: $k, status: $s, old: $o.value, new: $n.value }
      ]
  ;
def diff_properties:
      (.oldProperties | make_object_from_properties) as $old
    | (.newProperties | make_object_from_properties) as $new
    | diff_objects($old; $new) as $diff
    | foreach $diff[] as $d ({ id: .ID.S };
          select($d.status != "same")
        | .old = ((select(any("remove", "change"; . == $d.status)) | "[\($d.key) : \($d.old)]") // null)
        | .new = ((select(any("add", "change";    . == $d.status)) | "[\($d.key) : \($d.new)]") // null)
      )
    ;
[.Items[] | diff_properties]
```

This yields the following output:

```
[
  {
    "id": "ID_Complete",
    "old": "[property_A : value_A_old]",
    "new": "[property_A : value_A_new]"
  },
  {
    "id": "ID_Complete",
    "old": "[property_B : value_B_old]",
    "new": "[property_B : value_B_new]"
  },
  {
    "id": "ID_Incomplete",
    "old": null,
    "new": "[property_A : value_A_new]"
  },
  {
    "id": "ID_Incomplete",
    "old": "[property_B : value_B_old]",
    "new": "[property_B : value_B_new]"
  }
]
```

It seems like your data is in some kind of encoded format too. For a more robust solution, you should consider defining some functions to decode them.  Consider approaches found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28593471/how-to-simplify-aws-dynamodb-query-json-output-from-the-command-line) on how you could do that.

Comment: Awesome response, thanks. Both this and the other work. Before accepting one however, I will be trying them out within the system that is already in place and see which of both can be better adapted to it (since the question presented a working and trimmed down example of a small portion of the data).

Comment: After several tests, I was able to better adjust (with fewer changes) the solution proposed in the other answer to my system. That's why I am accepting it, however I want to thank you for your detailed answer, it was of great value as well to better understand how jq works.