# Sync AWS DynamoDB data with local DynamoDB instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

If I am not wrong for local DynamoDB, the data is present in `shared-local-instance.db` file. Is there a way to sync data from DynamoDB on AWS with my local DynamoDB (shared-local-instance.db)?

Also if a new table is created on AWS DynamoDB, can I pull that also along with its records. I don't want to manually create a table or enter the records to get sync with my local DynamoDB table. Hoping to get easy way out of this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You'll need to export from one and import to the other. Some ideas [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18896329/export-data-from-dynamodb/55182580) and [here](https://dynobase.dev/#features).