# How to insert a new line in Linux shell script?

Tags: linux, bash, newline

I want to insert a new line between multiple echo statements. I have tried `echo "hello\n"`, but it is not working. It is printing `\n`. I want the desired output like this:

```
Create the snapshots

Snapshot created
```

Comment: [I think you want this. Very well explained](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8467424/echo-new-line-in-bash-prints-literal-n)

Comment: You could use printf instead of echo :
`printf "hello\n"`

Answer (score 247, accepted):

The simplest way to insert a new line between `echo` statements is to insert an `echo` without arguments, for example:

```
echo Create the snapshots
echo
echo Snapshot created
```

That is, `echo` without any arguments will print a blank line.

Another alternative to use a single `echo` statement with the `-e` flag and embedded newline characters `\n`:

```
echo -e "Create the snapshots\n\nSnapshot created"
```

However, this is not portable, as the `-e` flag doesn't work consistently in all systems. A better way if you really want to do this is using `printf`:

```
printf "Create the snapshots\n\nSnapshot created\n"
```

This works more reliably in many systems, though it's not POSIX compliant. Notice that you must manually add a `\n` at the end, as `printf` doesn't append a newline automatically as `echo` does.

Comment: but what would be the equivalent for 
`echo "i want to be on one line"

echo "i want to be on another"` by using one echo command, and just \n, so that when you have long sentences, you can wrap your text in bash(using maybe 3 or 4 bash lines atleast with only one echo command.  I came here hoping to find that answer.  e.g. elaborate your final answer to make it multiple lines with one echo command, what if i wanted to cut it off right at `Snapshot created` on my bash file and make that a new bash line, without adding echo command?  I think use plus `+` somehow right?

Comment: @blamb you can break a line using `\` at the end of a line. But that's a very different topic from what was asked here.

Answer (score 85):

Use this echo statement

```
 echo -e "Hai\nHello\nTesting\n"
```

The output is

```
Hai
Hello
Testing
```

Comment: Thanks for the use of parameter for echo. One line command is good.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. It does not require multiple repetition of `echo` to print in multiple lines.

Answer (score 28):

```
echo $'Create the snapshots\nSnapshot created\n'
```

Comment: Thanks @ohad-cohen. This seems to be the only solution that can be redirected to a file

Comment: This is a cool technique. Any idea why this works?

Comment: I don't remember where I saw this first, but I believe it goes through bash vars mechanism

Answer (score 17):

You could use the [printf(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/printf.1.html) *command*, e.g. like

```
printf "Hello times %d\nHere\n" $[2+3]
```

The  `printf` command may accept arguments and needs a format control string similar (but not exactly the same) to the one for the standard *C* [printf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html) function...

Comment: is `printf` works for shell ?

Comment: The `printf` command and the `printf` library function are similar, but not the same.