# Parse text with newline using argparse

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse

In Python, using [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#module-argparse), is there any way to parse text containing a newline character given as a parameter?

I have this script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(formatter_class=argparse.RawTextHelpFormatter)
parser.add_argument('text', help='some text with newline')

args = parser.parse_args(["line1\nline2"])

print(args.text)
```

which prints as expected:

```
line1
line2
```

but if I give the argument at the command-line (after changing to `args = parser.parse_args()` in the script above) it's not doing the same. For example:

```
$ ./newline2argparse.py "line1\nline2"
line1\nline2
```

Any ideas on this?

Comment: Your shell doesn't interpret `\n` as a line break. Is that bash you're using?

Comment: `which $SHELL` prints `/bin/bash`. I'm on a Mac OS. But there should be a way to deal with this within the python script?

Comment: According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25269126/1222951) you can use `./newline2argparse.py $'line1\nline2'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `\n` is taken as `\` followed by `n` and not interpreted as it should. Use a command like `echo` or `printf` to correctly interpret it. This should work on almost any shell (`sh`, `bash`, `zsh`, etc).

```
$ ./newline2argparse.py "$(echo -en 'line1\nline2')"
$ ./newline2argparse.py "$(printf 'line1\nline2')"
$ ./newline2argparse.py `printf "line1\nline2"`
```

There are plenty of alternatives.

Comment: accepted this answer because it seems more "universal" across shells but @Barmar answer's is more concise for `bash`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want escape sequences to be processed in a shell string, surround it with `$''`

```
./newline2argparse.py $'line1\nline2'
```

Note that this is a `bash` extension, it may not be supported by all other shells.