# Parse text with newline and write it to file using argparse

Tags: python, argparse

I want to pass some strings with the new lines in command into the file, but `argparse` did not deal with the `\n` as the file `aaa` showed in the following script with the command `python test.py -t "aa\nbb\ncc\n"`.

The `test.py` is here:

```py
#! /usr/bin/env  python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import argparse


def wwrite():
    # parser
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        description='Atest.')
    parser.add_argument('-t', '--tail',
                        help='Add some lines to file')
    args = parser.parse_args()

    # check
    if args.tail is not None:
        zz_tail = str(args.tail)
    else:
        zz_tail = ''

    # write
    with open("aaa", 'w', encoding='utf-8') as fw:
        fw.write(zz_tail)

    with open("bbb", 'w', encoding='utf-8') as fw:
        fw.write("aa\nbb\ncc")


# 主文件
if __name__ == "__main__":
    wwrite()
```

How do I get the file same to this:

```
aa
bb
cc
```

Not:

```
aa\nbb\ncc\n
```

And not change the command `python test.py -t "aa\nbb\ncc\n"`.

There is a similar question and answer, but it will change the command to `python test.py -t $'aa\nbb\ncc\n'`. ([Parse text with newline using argparse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50642064/parse-text-with-newline-using-argparse))

Comment: The question is whether you can change the the 2 character '\n' to newline is the shell (bash?), or have to do it after parsing?  `args.tail` is already a string (if it isn't `None`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```py
zz_tail = args.tail.replace('\\n', '\n')
```