# How can I debug a Bash function that returns a value, and how can I add newlines to a variable?

Tags: bash, scripting, ubuntu-14.04

This is a Bash function that [returns a value](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/return-values-bash-functions), via *echo*:

```
#!/bin/bash
get_hello_name() {
  echo 'Hello $1!'
}
msg=$(get_hello_name "x")
echo $msg
```

Output:

```
$ bash ./initial_script5.sh
Hello $1!
```

I then incorrectly thought that the *last* echo was returned (I come from [Java](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_%28programming_language%29) and [Python](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_%28programming_language%29)), and was trying to use echo to debug the rest of the function.

And then I was wondering why the heck I could not print out newlines in my echo statements, despite trying *every single suggestion* in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8467424/echo-new-line-in-bash-prints-literal-n).

This script demonstrates the problem:

```
#!/bin/bash
a_function() {
  echo "---In function"

  printf %"s\n" hello world
  printf "Hello\nworld"
  echo $'hello\nworld'
  echo -e 'hello\nworld'
}

echo "---Pre function"
printf %"s\n" hello world
printf "Hello\nworld"
echo $'hello\nworld'
echo -e 'hello\nworld'

x=$(a_function "x")
echo $x

echo "---Post function"
printf %"s\n" hello world
printf "Hello\nworld"
echo $'hello\nworld'
echo -e 'hello\nworld'
```

```
$ bash ./initial_script5.sh
---Pre function
hello
world
Hello
worldhello
world
hello
world
---In function hello world Hello worldhello world hello world
---Post function
hello
world
Hello
worldhello
world
hello
world
```

The problem is that *all* of the echos in the function are concatenated together, *after being individually trimmed*, and then returned as a whole.

So this leads me to two questions: How do you debug a function that returns a value, and how do you append newlines onto a variable (not that I even want to do the latter, necessarily, but I would like to understand it)?

Comment: Wrote about this adventure on my blog: aliteralmind.wordpress.com/2015/01/10/bashcrash

Comment: Wrote about this adventure on my blog: http://aliteralmind.wordpress.com/2015/01/10/bashcrash

Comment: There's now an https version of that Linux Journal link: https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/return-values-bash-functions

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### Why the newlines seemed to disappear from the variable

The newlines are actually retained in the variable.  They do not display because the variable in the `echo` statement is not enclosed in double-quotes.  From the code:

```
echo $x
```

When using a variable *without* double-quotes, *word splitting* is performed.  Under the default `$IFS` ([wiki entry on IFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internal_field_separator)), this means that all collections of whitespace, including newlines and tabs, are replaced with single space.

To avoid that, simply use double quotes as in:

```
echo "$x"
```

With that single change, the output of your script becomes:

```
$ bash a,sh 
---Pre function
hello
world
Hello
worldhello
world
hello
world
---In function
hello
world
Hello
worldhello
world
hello
world
---Post function
hello
world
Hello
worldhello
world
hello
world
```

The newlines that were always in the variable `x` are now displayed.

#### Aside: the two words that remain strung together

Note that the combination `worldhello` appears on one line because because that is what the code asked for:

```
printf "Hello\nworld"
echo $'hello\nworld'
```

The `printf` does not print a newline after `world`.  Hence, that `world` appears on the same line as the `hello` which follows.

#### Documentation of the Details

`man bash` explains that double-quotes inhibit word splitting:

> If the substitution appears within double quotes, word splitting and pathname expansion are not performed on the results.

Word-splitting happens *after* variable expansion, command
substitution, and arithmetic expansion:

> The shell scans the results of parameter expansion, command
> substitution, and arithmetic expansion that did not occur within
> double quotes for    word splitting.

Another subtlety is that word splitting is performed only if some substitution took place:

> Note that if no expansion occurs, no splitting is performed.

Normally, when word splitting is performed, all strings of  spaces, tabs, and newlines are replaced by a single space.  This default behavior can be changed by changing the value of the `IFS` variable:

> The  shell treats each character of IFS as a delimiter, and splits the
> results of the other expansions into words on these characters.  If
> IFS   is unset, or its value is exactly , the
> default, then sequences of space, tab, and newline at the
> beginning and end       of the results of the previous expansions are
> ignored, and any sequence of IFS characters not at the beginning or
> end serves to delimit words.  If IFS has a value other than the
> default, then sequences of the whitespace characters space and tab are
> ignored at the beginning and  end  of       the  word,  as  long  as
> the whitespace character is in the value of IFS (an IFS whitespace
> character).  Any character in IFS that is not IFS    whitespace, along
> with any adjacent IFS whitespace characters, delimits a field.  A
> sequence of IFS whitespace characters is also treated as a delimiter.  If the value of IFS is null, no word splitting occurs.

### How to Debug

1. Use `set -x`

   Place the line `set -x` at the beginning of the code that you wish to run.  The results of evaluating each line will be displayed as the function is run, each preceded by `PS4` (default is `+`, space) to distinguish it from normal output.

   The debug output can be turned off by including the line `set +x`.

   `set -x` and `set +x` both also work on the command line.
2. Use `stderr`

   Send debug output to `stderr` (file descriptor 2) as follows:

   ```
   echo "My Debug Info" >&2
   ```

   By default, pipelines and command substitutions only operate on `stderr`.  Consequently, information sent to `stderr` will, by default, appear on the terminal.

#### More on `echo`

By default, `echo` ignores escape characters and the sequence `\n` simply means a `\` followed by an `n`:

```
$ echo "Hello\nworld 4"
Hello\nworld 4
```

To have `\n` interpreted as a newline, use `-e`:

```
$ echo -e "Hello\nworld 4"
Hello
world 4
```

Comment: Thank you for such a thorough answer. A follow up question is at the bottom of my question post.

Comment: @aliteralmind Your welcome.  I added a section to the end of the answer for your follow-up question on the issue of `echo` treating `\n` as a newline or not.

Comment: Ohhhhh. I got it! I thought you were talking about quoting *every* echo line, with 'x' just serving as a placeholder/dummy value. You mean leaving my original code exactly as it is, with a single change: The line after the function call, put *that* x in double quotes. Now it works perfectly, including your updated `-e` comment. I wish I could give you more upvotes!!

Comment: Added an answer containing a working version, based on your advice.

Comment: Wrote about this adventure on my blog: https://aliteralmind.wordpress.com/2015/01/10/bashcrash/

Comment: @aliteralmind: It's not even just "every echo line", it's (almost) every variable reference. Basically, anytime you see `$something` in a shell script, there should be double-quotes around it (unless there's a specific reason to avoid them). (There are some cases where it doesn't matter, but it's easier and safer to just always double-quote than to figure out when it's safe to leave them off.)

Comment: @GordonDavisson: Good to know. Will keep that in mind.

Comment: Perhaps also cover `echo ${x}` (whether it is any different from `echo $x` or not) in your answer?

Answer (score 2):

The working code after following [John1024's tips](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27872069/how-can-i-debug-a-bash-function-that-returns-a-value-and-how-can-i-add-newlines/27872114#27872114) (note the newlines print in the "1" lines, but not the "4", because of the `e` option):

```
#!/bin/bash
a_function() {
    echo -e "Hello\nworld\n 1"
    echo "Hello"
    echo "world"
    echo "Hello\nworld 4"
}

echo -e "Hello\nworld\n 1"
echo "Hello"
echo "world"
echo "Hello\nworld 4"

x=$(a_function "x")
echo "x-no-quotes>"
echo $x                       # No new lines!
echo "<x-no-quotes"

echo "x-in-double-quotes>"
echo "$x"                     # Yes new lines!
echo "<x-in-double-quotes"

echo -e "Hello\nworld\n 1"
echo "Hello"
echo "world"
echo "Hello\nworld 4"
```

Output:

```
Hello
world
 1
Hello
world
Hello\nworld 4
x-no-quotes>
Hello world 1 Hello world Hello\nworld 4
<x-no-quotes
x-in-double-quotes>
Hello
world
 1
Hello
world
Hello\nworld 4
<x-in-double-quotes
Hello
world
 1
Hello
world
Hello\nworld 4
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to call it with a double quote:

```
echo "$x"
```

However, if you would want to explicitly show what you typed inside, also known as literal expression, use a single quote:

```
echo '$x'
```