# How can I set Bash aliases for docker containers in Dockerfile?

Tags: bash, unix, docker, alias, dockerfile

I am new to Docker. I found that we can set environment variables using the *ENV* instruction in the Dockerfile. But how does one set Bash aliases for long commands in Dockerfile?

Answer (score 259, accepted):

Basically like you always do, by adding it to the user's [`.bashrc`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell)#Legacy-compatible_Bash_startup_example) file:

```
FROM foo
RUN echo 'alias hi="echo hello"' >> ~/.bashrc
```

As usual this will only work for interactive shells:

```
docker build -t test .
docker run -it --rm --entrypoint /bin/bash test hi
/bin/bash: hi: No such file or directory
docker run -it --rm test bash
$ hi
hello
```

For non-interactive shells you should create a small script and put it in your path, i.e.:

```
RUN echo -e '#!/bin/bash\necho hello' > /usr/bin/hi && \
    chmod +x /usr/bin/hi
```

If your alias uses parameters (ie. `hi Jim` -> `hello Jim`), just add `"$@"`:

```
RUN echo -e '#!/bin/bash\necho hello "$@"' > /usr/bin/hi && \
    chmod +x /usr/bin/hi
```

Comment: Thanks for this can you provide an example of non interactive shell? I was looking for ENTRYPOINT and CMD to solve this

Comment: Bash alias only works in interactive shells. Just create a small shell script and put in your path, same effect as an alias. Updated the answer with a simple example.

Comment: Note: from https://stackoverflow.com/a/8467449 you should rather use **printf** instead of *echo* to ensure more consistent behavior.

So

    printf '#!/bin/bash\necho hello' > /usr/bin/hi
    chmod +x /usr/bin/hi

Comment: You should use "$@" instead of $* for multiple arguments escaping. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/248464/escape-shell-arg-from-one-script-to-another

Comment: How to put that script inside PATH?

Comment: Execute `echo $PATH` in your container, copy your script into one of the listed directories.

Comment: For me `-e` didn't work in case of non-interactive shells. Removing the same worked like a charm.

Answer (score 27):

To create an alias of an existing command, might also use `ln -s`:

```
ln -s $(which <existing_command>) /usr/bin/<my_command>
```

Comment: I wouldn't call this an alias .. it is a soft link / symlink. The convenience of aliases is that you can pass parameters to the command like `alias ll='ls -lh'` which is not possible with symlinks.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to use aliases just in Dockerfile, but not inside a container then the shortest way is the [`ENV` declaration](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#env):

```
ENV update='apt-get update -qq'
ENV install='apt-get install -qq'

RUN $update && $install apt-utils \
    curl \
    gnupg \
    python3.6
```

And for use in a container the way like already described:

```
 RUN printf '#!/bin/bash \n $(which apt-get) install -qq $@' > /usr/bin/install
 RUN chmod +x /usr/bin/install
```

Most of the time I use aliases just in the building stage and do not go inside containers, so the first example is quicker, clearer and simpler for every day use.

Answer (score 5):

I think the easiest way would be to mount a file into your container containing your aliases, and then specify where Bash should find it:

```
docker run \
    -it \
    --rm \
    -v ~/.bash_aliases:/tmp/.bash_aliases \
    [image] \
    /bin/bash --init-file /tmp/.bash_aliases
```

Sample usage:

```
echo 'alias what="echo it works"' > my_aliases
docker run -it --rm -v ~/my_aliases:/tmp/my_aliases ubuntu:18.04 /bin/bash --init-file /tmp/my_aliases
alias
```

Output:

```
alias what='echo it works'
```

```
what
```

Output:

```
it works
```

Answer (score 4):

I just added this to my *app.dockerfile* file:

```
# Set up aliases
ADD ./bashrc_alias.sh /usr/sbin/bashrc_alias.sh
ADD ./initbash_profile.sh /usr/sbin/initbash_profile
RUN chmod +x /usr/sbin/initbash_profile
RUN /bin/bash -C "/usr/sbin/initbash_profile"
```

And inside the *initbash_profile.sh* file which just appends my custom aliases and no need to source the *[.bashrc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell)#Legacy-compatible_Bash_startup_example)* file:

```
# Add the Bash aliases
cat /usr/sbin/bashrc_alias.sh >> ~/.bashrc
```

It worked a treat!

Another option is to just use the "docker exec -it <container-name> command" from outside the container and just use your own *.bashrc* or the *.bash_profile* file (what ever you prefer).

E.g.,

```
docker exec -it docker_app_1 bash
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [ENTRYPOINT](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint), but it will not work for aliases, in your Dockerfile:

```
ADD dev/entrypoint.sh /opt/entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/opt/entrypoint.sh"]
```

Your `entrypoint.sh` file:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

function dev_run()
{

}

export -f dev_run

exec "$@"
```

Comment: Pay attention that some Docker image could already override default entrypoint (such as phusion base image).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a Bash function to have your aliases in every container you use interactively.

```
ducker_it() {
    docker cp ~/bin/alias.sh "$1":/tmp
    docker exec -it "$1" /bin/bash -c "[[ ! -f /tmp/alias.sh.done ]] \
        && [[ -w /root/.bashrc ]] \
        && cat /tmp/alias.sh >> /root/.bashrc \
        && touch /tmp/alias.sh.done"
    docker exec -it "$1" /bin/bash
}
```

Required step before:

```
grep ^alias ~/.zshrc > ~/bin/alias.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

Used some of the previous solutions, but the aliases are not recognised still.

I'm trying to set aliases and use them both within later Dockerfile steps and in the container at runtime.

```
RUN echo "alias model-downloader='python3 ${MODEL_DL_PATH}/downloader.py'" >> ~/.bash_aliases && \
    echo "alias model-converter='python3 ${MODEL_DL_PATH}/converter.py'" >> ~/.bash_aliases && \
    source ~/.bash_aliases

# Download the model
RUN model-downloader --name $MODEL_NAME -o $MODEL_DIR --precisions $MODEL_PRECISION;
```

The solution for me was to use ENV variables that held folder paths and then add the exact executable. I could have use ARG too, but for more of my scenarios I needed the aliases in both the build stage and later in the runtime.

I used the ENV variables in conjunction with a Bash script that runs once dependencies have ponged and sets the Bash source, sets some more env variables, and allows for further commands to pipe through.

Comment: Every `RUN` instruction is executed in a new shell, so in your example the alias file is no longer loaded when you try to use the alias.

Comment: 100% @ErikDannenberg thank you for the comment and also for reminding me that I need to post an update to this - I've uncovered a solution and it's very much like you suggested.

Comment: What is "ponged"? [Not](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pong#Verb) *"(Britain, Australia, New Zealand, slang) To stink, to smell bad."*, I presume. Or *"(slang, theater, derogatory) To deliver a line of a play in an arch, suggestive or unnatural way, so as to draw undue attention to it."* or *"(slang, theater, intransitive) To invent a line of dialogue when one has forgotten the actual line. "*?

Answer (score 0):

[@ErikDannenberg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5731095/erik-dannenberg)'s answer did the trick, but in my case, some adjustments were needed.

It didn't work with aliases cause apparently there's an issue with interactive shells.

I reached for his second solution, but it still didn't really work. I checked existing shell scripts in my project and noticed the head comment (first line = `#!/usr/bin/env sh`) differs a bit from `#!/usr/bin/bash`. After changing it accordingly it started working for my `t` and `tc` "aliases", but I had to use the addendum to his second solution for getting `tf` to work.

Here's the complete Dockerfile

```
FROM php:8.1.1-fpm-alpine AS build

RUN apk update && apk add git

RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php && mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer

RUN apk add --no-cache $PHPIZE_DEPS \
    && pecl install xdebug \
    && docker-php-ext-enable xdebug \
    && touch /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/99-xdebug.ini \
    && echo "xdebug.mode=coverage" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/99-xdebug.ini \
    && echo -e '#!/usr/bin/env sh\nphp artisan test' > /usr/bin/t \
    && chmod +x /usr/bin/t \
    && echo -e '#!/usr/bin/env sh\nphp artisan test --coverage' > /usr/bin/tc \
    && chmod +x /usr/bin/tc \
    && echo -e '#!/usr/bin/env sh\nphp artisan test --filter "$@"' > /usr/bin/tf \
    && chmod +x /usr/bin/tf

WORKDIR /var/www
```