# How can I set an alias in the .bashrc of my Docker image

Tags: docker, dockerfile

For example:
'alias python=/home/user/python3.6'
Is something I might want to put into my bashrc
How do I set this in a Dockerfile
I know of the ENV command which sets path variable, is it possible to do similar for setting an alias?

Comment: just put that line into your .bashrc file and ADD it to your Dockerfile

Answer (score 11, accepted):

simply use RUN to add an alias to `bash_profile`.

```
FROM ubuntu
MAINTAINER Mojtaba Yeganeh

RUN echo "alias python=/home/user/python3.6" >> ~/.bash_profile
```

Comment: shouldn't this be simply `RUN echo "alias python=..." >> ~/.bash_profile`? https://stackoverflow.com/a/36388856/5339857

Comment: i meant you have double `alias alias` there

Answer (score 0):

For me it worked in **.bashrc** file.

I've put this in **Dockerfile**:

```
RUN echo "alias ll='ls -alF'" >> ~/.bashrc
```