# How to use scl enable to run python3 app in dockerfile

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, dockerfile

Im trying to run a python3 application in a docker container using CentOS 7 as the base image. So if I'm just playing with it interactively, I type `scl enable rh-python36 bash`

That obviously switches my standard python2 environment to the python3.6 environment I install earlier(in the Dockerfile) Now, earlier in the dockerfile I run the following:

`SHELL ["scl", "enable", "rh-python36"]` (and many variations of this)

This enables me to do all of my pip installations in this python3 environment. However, when I actually want to run my app.py with CMD, it defaults to the python2. I've tried playing with ENTRYPOINT and variations of CMD, but I cant seem to make the python3 environment active when the container finally runs. How can I get this running correctly with python3?

Here's the dockerfile:

```
FROM centos:7
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app && \
  yum install -y centos-release-scl && \
  yum install -y rh-python36 && \
  yum install -y rh-python36-python-tkinter
SHELL ["scl", "enable", "rh-python36"]
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY . .
WORKDIR /usr/src/app/codeBase
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r /usr/src/app/codeBase/requirements.txt
EXPOSE 9000
CMD ["python",  "run.py"]
```

I've also tried the alias solution, but I'm afraid it doesnt change the python exe for the CMD: Here's the totally runnable version with that that still prints out python 2.7.5:

```
FROM centos:7
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app && \  
  yum install -y centos-release-scl && \
  yum install -y rh-python36 && \
  yum install -y rh-python36-python-tkinter
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
RUN alias python=$(find / -type f -name "python*" | grep "python3.6$")
CMD ["python",  "-V"]
```

It just seems as though none of this persists in the new shell created with CMD

Comment: Putting an `alias` in your `Dockerfile` is completely misdirected. You should probably avoid aliases entirely anyway; but the way to define an alias in a Dockerfile is to add the alias definition to the shell's initialization file in the Docker image.

Comment: @tripleee Yea, I really don't like the alias as a solution. I figured there would be a more docker friendly solution to this. I just posted an answer below that works for me. I don't see any less convoluted way to achieve this though.

Answer (score 2):

### Note:

I am leaving this answer up as context to the question, but this does *not* solve the issue. My attempt was to modify where `python` is pointing, but if executing in a `RUN` command, the shell will exit and you'll lose the `alias`. Modifying the `PYTHONPATH` via bash is also a no-go, per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34911622/dockerfile-set-env-to-result-of-command). Thanks to @tripleee for the catch

Unfortunately, it looks like `yum install -y rh-python36` puts that python3.6 in a really weird spot:

```sh
find / -type f -name "python*" | grep "python3.6$"
/opt/rh/rh-python36/root/usr/bin/python3.6
```

You can use that to `alias` your `python` command in your `Dockerfile`:

```
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app && \
  yum install -y centos-release-scl && \
  yum install -y rh-python36 && \
  yum install -y rh-python36-python-tkinter

# Here
RUN alias python=$(find / -type f -name "python*" | grep "python3.6$")
```

Which should allow you to retain your `CMD` and also ties it to the correct `site-packages`:

```py
import sys

sys.path
['', '/opt/rh/rh-python36/root/usr/lib64/python36.zip', '/opt/rh/rh-python36/root/usr/lib64/python3.6', '/opt/rh/rh-python36/root/usr/lib64/python3.6/lib-dynload', '/opt/rh/rh-python36/root/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages', '/opt/rh/rh-python36/root/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages']
```

It looks like this also might remove the need to `scl enable` that python environment, as you can then just use `python -m pip...`:

```sh
# No scl has been run
python -m pip install requests
```

```py
# running python in the terminal
import requests

r = requests.get('http://google.com')
# runs like a charm
```

Comment: It looks like, for me, the alias does not work. Wit the new minimal dockerfile example I posted above, I'm still getting python 2 when I run the CMD

Comment: And I guess merely overriding the Python executable won't provide you with the correct `PYTHONPATH` etc (and of course as pointed out elsewhere, interactively defining an alias in your Dockerfile will simply define it in a sh ll instance which then immediately exits).

Comment: @tripleee you're right, worked for me because I was running the command in a single bash session and not taking into account that the `RUN` will exit that shell to start a new one in a different layer. In that case, you could modify `PYTHONPATH` with an environment variable in that directory. I'll edit my answer

Comment: Though you'll still need to reverse engineer what *exactly* `scl enable` does and reimplement everything. So I'm thinking better to figure out how to use the command itself. I'm not a Red Hat / CentOS person so I'm not too familiar with this command.

Comment: I'm not either, which is why I went this way

Comment: @tripleee Looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34911622/dockerfile-set-env-to-result-of-command) question, looks like docker does not support exporting env vars as output of shell commands. So, learning to actually use `scl enable` is the way forward. I'll leave my answer, but I'll add the caveat in an edit

Answer (score 2):

`SHELL` is completely the wrong `Dockerfile` command for this. You'll probably want to put that in a `RUN`  stanza instead.

The purpose of `SHELL` is to define the shell used to execute `RUN` commands. So something like

```
SHELL ["sh", "-c"] # The default
RUN echo "foo"
```

ends up running

```
sh -c 'echo "foo"'
```

Of course, replacing `SHELL` with a command which doesn't support this use case will simply break the `RUN` command for you.

Maybe try something like

```
FROM centos:7
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app && \
  yum install -y centos-release-scl && \
  yum install -y rh-python36 && \
  yum install -y rh-python36-python-tkinter
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY . .
WORKDIR /usr/src/app/codeBase
RUN scl enable rh-python36 pip install --no-cache-dir -r ./requirements.txt
EXPOSE 9000
CMD ["scl", "enable", "rh-python36", "python",  "run.py"]
```

Comment: Ah, so that explains why all the packages install correctly with pip after running that, but not the CMD itself

Comment: Unfortunately putting it all in the CMD didn't work for me. scl seems to create a new shell, where the python runs in the same shell that scl ran in.

Comment: Wait, try `CMD ["scl", "enable", "rh-python36", "sh", "-c", "python ./run.py"]`

Answer (score 2):

So I figured this out thanks to the answer from C.Nivs and an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36388465/how-to-set-bash-aliases-for-docker-containers-in-dockerfile). The alias works in an interactive shell, but not for the CMD. What I ended up doing was similar, only in my case I'm creating a new executable in /usr/bin that calls the special python36 exe:

```
RUN echo -e '#!/bin/bash\n$(find / -type f -name "python*" | grep "python3.6$") "$@"' > /usr/bin/py3 && \
    chmod +x /usr/bin/py3
CMD ["py3",  "-V"]
```

now py3 runs a script calling the python3 install specifically with whatever argument

Comment: But then you get the wrong versions of the modules you just installed because your `PYYHONPATH` is wrong, don't you?

Comment: @tripleee interestingly, it's looking like it ties to the correct directories. Looking at `sys.path`: `['', "/usr/src/app/$(find / -type f -name 'python*' | grep 'python3.6$')", '/opt/rh/rh-python36/root/usr/lib64/python36.zip', '/opt/rh/rh-python36/root/usr/lib64/python3.6', '/opt/rh/rh-python36/root/usr/lib64/python3.6/lib-dynload', '/opt/rh/rh-python36/root/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages', '/opt/rh/rh-python36/root/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages']`. Though the second entry is... concerning but doesn't seem to throw `FileNotFoundError`

Comment: Nah, you can have any junk you want in there, it will just silently ignore directories which don't exist.

Comment: @tripleee What ended up getting this working for me is that before installing with pip, I left in `SHELL ["scl", "enable", "rh-python36"]` Which seems to then let everything install in the right place with the right pip, because i can then access everything i downloaded in my py3

Answer (score 0):

Configuring the shell environment variables by overriding them all to use scl_source, as seen from following "Method #2" from Austin Dewey's [blog](https://austindewey.com/2019/03/26/enabling-software-collections-binaries-on-a-docker-image/) works for me.

```
FROM centos:7
SHELL ["/usr/bin/env", "bash", "-c"]
RUN \
    yum install -y centos-release-scl && \
    yum install -y rh-python38-python-devel
ENV \
    BASH_ENV="/usr/bin/scl_enable" \
    ENV="/usr/bin/scl_enable" \
    PROMPT_COMMAND=". /usr/bin/scl_enable"
RUN echo -e "\n\
unset BASH_ENV PROMPT_COMMAND ENV\n\
source scl_source enable rh-python38\n\
" > /usr/bin/scl_enable
RUN \
    python3 -m ensurepip && \
    python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip && \
    python3 -m pip install setuptools wheel
```

```sh
docker build --tag python:3.8-centos7 - < Dockerfile
docker run --rm -i -t python:3.8-centos7
python3 --version
```

> Python 3.8.11

**NOTE:** This does not work when giving `python3 --version` as command. I have not been able to figure out a work-around.

```sh
docker run --rm -i -t python:3.8-centos7 python3 --version
```