# How to set default python3 to py3.8 in the Dockerfile?

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker

I tried to alias `python3` to `python3.8` in the Dockerfile. But It doesn't work for me. I am using `ubuntu:18.04`.

```
Step 25/41 : RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y python3.8
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 9fa81ca14a53
Step 26/41 : RUN alias python3="python3.8" && python3 --version
 ---> Running in d7232d3c8b8f
Python 3.6.9
```

As you can see the python3 is still 3.6.9. How can I fix this issue?
Thanks.

**EDIT**
Just attach my Dockerfile:

```
##################################################################################################################
# Build
#################################################################################################################
#FROM openjdk:8
FROM ubuntu:18.04

############## Linux and perl packages ###############
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y openjdk-8-jdk && \
    apt-get install -y ant && \
    apt-get clean && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* && \
    rm -rf /var/cache/oracle-jdk8-installer && \
    apt-get update -y && \
    apt-get install curl groff python-gdbm -y;
# Fix certificate issues, found as of 
# https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ca-certificates-java/+bug/983302
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y ca-certificates-java && \
    apt-get clean && \
    update-ca-certificates -f && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* && \
    rm -rf /var/cache/oracle-jdk8-installer;
# Setup JAVA_HOME, this is useful for docker commandline
ENV JAVA_HOME /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/
RUN export JAVA_HOME
# install git
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y mysql-server && \
    apt-get install -y uuid-runtime git jq python python-dev python-pip python-virtualenv libdbd-mysql-perl && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* && \
    apt-get install perl && \
    perl -MCPAN -e 'CPAN::Shell->install("Inline")' && \
    perl -MCPAN -e 'CPAN::Shell->install("DBI")' && \
    perl -MCPAN -e 'CPAN::Shell->install("List::MoreUtils")' && \
    perl -MCPAN -e 'CPAN::Shell->install("Inline::Python")' && \
    perl -MCPAN -e 'CPAN::Shell->install("LWP::Simple")' && \
    perl -MCPAN -e 'CPAN::Shell->install("JSON")' && \
    perl -MCPAN -e 'CPAN::Shell->install("LWP::Protocol::https")';
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install --yes cpanminus
RUN cpanm \
    CPAN::Meta \
    YAML \
    DBI \
    Digest::SHA \
    Module::Build \
    Test::Most \
    Test::Weaken \
    Test::Memory::Cycle \
    Clone
# Install perl modules for network and SSL (and their dependencies)
RUN apt-get install --yes \
    openssl \
    libssl-dev \
    liblwp-protocol-https-perl
RUN cpanm \
    LWP \
    LWP::Protocol::https
# New module for v1.2 annotation
RUN perl -MCPAN -e 'CPAN::Shell->install("Text::NSP::Measures::2D::Fisher::twotailed")'
#############################################
############## python packages ###############
# python packages
RUN pip install pymysql==0.10.1 awscli boto3 pandas docopt fastnumbers tqdm pygr

############## python3 packages ###############
# python3 packages
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y python3-pip && \
    python3 -m pip install numpy && \
    python3 -m pip install pandas && \
    python3 -m pip install sqlalchemy && \
    python3 -m pip install boto3 && \
    python3 -m pip install pymysql && \
    python3 -m pip install pymongo;
RUN python3 -m pip install pyfaidx
#############################################

#############################################
############# expose tcp ports
EXPOSE 3306/tcp
EXPOSE 80/tcp
EXPOSE 8080
############# RUN entrypoint.sh
# commented out for testing
ENTRYPOINT ["./entrypoint.sh"]
© 2022 GitHub, Inc.
Terms
```

When I install the package `pyfaidx` with default python3.6, it raises an error. I found that python3.8 can install it. Thus, I want to switch to python3.8 to install all py3 packages.

Comment: Add this way at the top of your Dockerfile `FROM python:3.8-slim-buster`

Comment: My first thought is that you should publish the Dockerfile. It would be important to know which base image you are using, for example.

Comment: @Duate P, thanks for your suggestion, I attached my Dockerfile.

Comment: Consider breaking this up into several smaller Dockerfiles.  Rather than have one massive image that has Java _and_ Perl _and_ Python_ and all of the individual per-language dependencies, if you can create an image that has only the Python component then you can use the `python` image as a base, as @AlwaysSunny suggests.  You can then use a tool like Docker Compose to launch the various per-component containers in parallel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bash `alias` that you define in your `RUN` statement will be available only in the current shell session. When the current `RUN` statement finishes executing, you exit the session, effectively forgetting any aliases you set up there.

See also: [How can I set Bash aliases for docker containers in Dockerfile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36388465/how-can-i-set-bash-aliases-for-docker-containers-in-dockerfile)

Another option is to use `update-alternatives`, e.g.,

```
# update-alternatives --install `which python3` python3 `which python3.8` 20
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/python3.8 to provide /usr/bin/python3 (python3) in auto mode
# python3 --version
Python 3.8.0
```

This may interfere with other container packages that do require 3.6 which was default on Ubuntu 18.04 back in the day. Furthermore, `pip`'s authors do not recommend using `pip` to install system-wide packages like that. In fact, newer `pip` versions will emit a warning when attempting to use `pip` globally along the lines of your `Dockerfile`.

Therefore a better course of action is using a virtualenv:

```
# apt install -y python3-venv python3.8-venv
...

# python3.8 -m venv /usr/local/venv
# /usr/local/venv/bin/pip install -U pip setuptools wheel 
# /usr/local/venv/bin/pip install -U pyfaidx    
... (etc)
```

You can also "enter" your virtualenv by activating it:

```
root@a1d0210118a8:/# source /usr/local/venv/bin/activate
(venv) root@a1d0210118a8:/# python -V
Python 3.8.0
```

See also: [Use different Python version with virtualenv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1534210/use-different-python-version-with-virtualenv).