# Prevent "echo" from interpreting backslash escapes

Tags: macos, terminal, echo, newline, zsh

I'd like to echo something to a file that contains new line escape sequences, however I would like them to remain escaped. I'm looking for basically the opposite to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8467424/echo-newline-in-bash-prints-literal-n) question.

```
echo "part1\npart2" >> file
```

I would like to look like this in the file

```
$ cat file
old
part1\npart2
```

but it looks like

```
$ cat file
old
part1
part2
```

Comment: That should work just like you posted it... doesn't it?

Comment: That should be the default behaviour https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/219268/how-to-add-new-lines-when-using-echo -- What operating system and what version of `echo` do you have?

Comment: Did you try `echo`?

Comment: This would happen if you have the `xpg_echo` shell option set ("expand backslash-escape sequences by default"). Is it? You can check with `shopt xpg_echo`.

Comment: For a portable way, you could use `printf '%s\n' 'part1\npart2' >> file`.

Comment: @BenjaminW. printf '%s\n' works! thank you :)

Comment: @BenjaminW. there probably is something wrong with the xpg_echo option. shopt doesn't seem to be installed either. I'm using iterm with zsh

Comment: Ah, I see. `shopt` is a Bash thing. [Zsh `echo`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html#Shell-Builtin-Commands) seems to interpret backslashes by default

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is a good example of why POSIX recommends using `printf` instead of `echo` (see [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html), under "application usage"): you don't know what you get with `echo`<sup>1</sup>.

You could get:

- A shell builtin `echo` that does not interpret backslash escapes by default

  - Example: the Bash builtin `echo` has an `-e` option to enable backslash escape interpretation and checks the `xpg_echo` shell option
- A shell builtin `echo` that interprets backslash escapes by default

  - Examples: zsh, dash
- A standalone executable `/bin/echo`: probably depends on which one – GNU Coreutils `echo` understands the `-e` option, like the Bash builtin

The POSIX spec says this (emphasis mine):

> The following operands shall be supported:
>   *`string`*
>   A string to be written to standard output. If the first operand is `-n`, or if any of the operands contain a `<backslash>` character, the **results are implementation-defined**.

So, for a portable solution, we can use `printf`:

```
printf '%s\n' 'part1\npart2' >> file
```

where the `\n` in the format string will always be interpreted, and the `\n` in the argument will never be interpreted, resulting in

```
part1\npart2
```

being appended to `file`.

---

<sup>1</sup> For an exhaustive overview of various behaviours for `echo` and `printf`, see [echo(1) and printf(1)](https://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/echo+printf/) on in-ulm.de.