# PTC Integrity edit multiline field in issue

Tags: mks-integrity

How do I add a line break while editing a field via CLI?

`im editissue --field=comment="first line\nsecond line" ISSUE_NUMBER` just saves the whole string in one line with a **"\n"**

The comment field is a multiline field and it is possible to insert a line break in GUI.

OS is Windows 7, integrity version is 10.6

Comment: On which OS are you want to use the command?

Comment: OS is Windows 7, I added it to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it has more to do with the shell rather than the `im` utility itself.  ANSI-C Quoting appears to work on Git Bash/Windows:

```
im editissue --field=FieldName=$'test\ntest' 123456
```

The `$` causes the `\n` character in `''`-delimited text to be interpolated - see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8467424/echo-newline-in-bash-prints-literal-n) for more details.