# plink send long commands

Tags: ubuntu, echo, putty, plink

I am using Putty to communicate over a serial interface, and I want to automate two commands. The first is "sc" and the other is "long_command". Previously I used the command:

```
putty -load session_name
```

To quickly open upp the Putty terminal then I can write "sc" or "long_command" as expected. To automate this I use the plink command:

```
$ foo='sc\n\r'
$ echo "${foo@E}" | plink -load session_name
```

Which works, however with the longer command:

```
$ foo='long_command\n\r'
$ echo "${foo@E}" | plink -load session_name
```

The printed output is: "**long_comlong_co**"

To overcome this I created the script long_command.sh:

```
comm1='swup'
comm2='date'
comm3='\n\r' 
echo "${comm1@E}" | plink -load hydac& 
echo "${comm2@E}" | plink -load hydac&  
echo "${comm3@E}" | plink -load hydac& 
;
```

And run it with

```
$ ./long_command.sh
```

Which works but looks crappy and if I use this command:

```
foo='long_command\n\r'
echo "${foo@E}"
```

It nicely prints long_command with a newline so...
**How do I send longer commands to plink?**

I am on Ubuntu, with GNOME terminal, so if you have any other magic functions like screen or similar that you think is better I am all ears.

Comment: What is `@E`? What do you get with `echo "${foo@E}" | cat`?

Comment: I had a problem previously where the newline was not added correctly and found this answer on another question:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/51486326/7689257

If I use with cat I also get: long_command