# accessing elements in array in script

Tags: arrays, shell, for-loop, parameters

i am trying to print all parameters in bash script "one by one".
fro example i want to run:
    ./myscript hello all friends
and see below result:

```
 hello  
 all  
 friends.
```

i wrote below code:

```
#!/bin/bash
li=$@
for(( j=0;j<$#;j++));
do
    echo ${li[$j]}
done
```

bug when i run my code it prints all of argument at once:

```
hello all friends
```

i know i can do that by changing the for structure to below format:

```
#!/bin/bash
li=$@
for j in $li;
do
    echo $j
done
```

but i didn't want to change the code such as above.
please help me.
thank you in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8467424/echo-newline-in-bash-prints-literal-n

Comment: didn't work yet. it prints all elements and then print a new line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this:

```
#!/bin/bash
li=$@
for(( j=0;j<$#;j++)); do
    printf '%s\n' ${li[$j]}
done
```

Here you can find some info about formatting: 
https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/printf

Comment: it works fine, thank you.
but i have a question:
why i can't do that by echo?

Answer (score 1):

You can write using echo -n option to skip printing newline at the end.

```
echo -n ${li[$j]}
```

Check [docs](https://www.shellscript.sh/echo.html) here.

Comment: didn't work, i want to have new line after any word but it doesn't do that