# Bach: echo and newline

Tags: bash, echo

I need to output two digits each on a line. The result should be:

```
1 
2
```

I tried different approaches and have seen [the SO question "Echo newline in Bash prints literal \n"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8467424/echo-newline-in-bash-prints-literal-n).

I do understand this outputs:

```
bash> echo "1\n2"
1\n2
bash> echo -e "1\n2"
1
2
```

But what's going on here?

```
bash> sh -c echo "1\n2"

bash> sh
$ echo "1\n2"
1
2
$ exit
bash>
```

My shell is `/bin/bash`: GNU bash, version 4.3.48(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)

sh is linked to `/bin/dash`:

Comment: This is because the POSIX spec left this behavior decision up the people implementing it. If you want consistent printing behavior across all mostly POSIX-complaint shells, use `printf` instead.

Comment: "A string to be written to standard output. If the first operand is -n, or if any of the operands contain a backslash ( '\' ) character, the results are implementation-defined." https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/echo.html