# Why doesn't ${PATH//:/\n} output each path on a new line?

Tags: bash

Suppose

```
PATH=/this/is/path1:/this/is/path2:/this/is/path3
```

Why does

```
echo "${PATH//:/\n}" or echo -e "${PATH//:/\n}"
```

not output

```
this/is/path1
this/is/path2
this/is/path3
```

This is bash 4.4.20.

Comment: Try: `echo "${PATH//:/$'\n'}"`

Comment: `echo "${PATH//:/\n}"` works for me in `zsh`, and `echo "${PATH//:/$'\n'}"` works for me in `bash`.

Comment: Both of your bash suggestions work for me. What is the role of the second $?

Comment: In bash, "\n"  is simply a backslash followed by the letter _n_, as you can see by doing a `printf %s "\n"`. You would need this to translate to a newline when printing. From the man-page for `echo`  : _-e   :  enable interpretation of backslash escapes_

Comment: Please add your bash version. Also, take a look at [Echo newline in Bash prints literal \n](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8467424/echo-newline-in-bash-prints-literal-n)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stuff inside `${var//<here>/<and here>}` is escaped with `\`, so that you could write `\}` or `\/`. Like:

```
$ var=abc; echo "${var//b/\}}"
a}c
```

The `\n` is not special sequence, so it's just `n`:

```
$ var=abc; echo "${var//b/\n}"
anc
```

So with `"${PATH//:/\n}"` you are just only replacing `:` with `n`. Either replace `:` with an actual newline:

```
echo "${PATH//:/$'\n'}"
# or an actual actual newline
echo "${PATH//:/
}"
```

or you seem to want to replace it by a sequence of two characters `\n` and then use `echo -e` to tranform `\n` into newlines:

```
echo -e "${PATH//:/\\n}"
```

Comment: Or a POSIX shell alternative: `(IFS=:;printf %s\\n $PATH)` parenthesis sub-shell is to preserve IFS. or `OIFS=$IFS;IFS=:;printf %s\\n $PATH;IFS=$OIFS` without a sub-shell.

Answer (score 1):

The bash operator `${var//pattern/string/ }` is a variable expansion, which takes as input the value of the variable `var`, then replaces all matches of `pattern` by `string`.

In your example, to goal is to replace each separator `:` by `\n`, and print them with `echo -e` as a newline.

But to make it work, it is necessary to double the `\` to protect it, so the correct command is

```
echo -e "${PATH//:/\\n}"
```

For further informations, see in the [reference manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) the paragraph `${parameter/pattern/string}`.

Comment: I am confused by your answer. The example given DOES NOT work. See the discussion.

Comment: @Lucas I haven't finished my answer when you made your comment!

Comment: I understand. I decided to award the answer to @KamilKuk who posted a complete explanation before you completed your edit.