# How to write to a file with escape characters in bash

Tags: bash, shell

A very simple question. I'd like to write several lines to a file with just one line containing multiple `\n`. I.e. my input string would be `hello\nhello\nhello`, I'd like to write it to a file `hello.txt`, and when `cat hello.txt` it should give me

```
hello
hello
hello
```

However, when I do `echo "hello\nhello\nhello" > hello.txt`, it just gave me the literal string, without converting `\n` to a newline.

I wonder how to write such a line to a file.

Comment: Did you try `printf` instead of `echo`? [Echo newline in Bash prints literal \n](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8467424/echo-newline-in-bash-prints-literal-n)

Answer (score 0):

You want either `echo -e` or, generally even better `printf`

```
printf 'Hello %s\n\nWelcome to my %s document\nmultiline document\n\n\n\nEnd\n' \
       "John" "yellow" > "/some/path/hello.txt";
```